# C# Convert Excel 2007 (xlsx) file into Excel 2003 (xls) file

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-2007

I am working on a console application which will convert xlsx file into xls file. I don't want to rename it from xlsx to xls because it will get opened in excel 2007 but it will be shown as corrupted file in excel 2003. Looking for a way which will load the document and then it will be saved as xls format.

My current code Just renames the xlsx to xls

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\L-3\Desktop\my.xlsx";
string svfileName = @"C:\Users\L-3\Desktop\ssc\my1.xls";
object oMissing = Type.Missing;
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName, oMissing, oMissing,
                oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
wb.SaveAs(svfileName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLTemplate, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
app.Quit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with to save with `XlFileFormat.xlExcel9795`. You can also use `XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal`

Comment: This will save the file as Excel 95-97 format, if you are using any features introduced >= 2003, they won't work!

Comment: That throws an exception: "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Answer (score 4):

Your enum is wrong, instead of  **XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLTemplate** you want  **XlFileFormat.xlExcel8**, so your code would be like so:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\L-3\Desktop\my.xlsx";
string svfileName = @"C:\Users\L-3\Desktop\ssc\my1.xls";
object oMissing = Type.Missing;
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName, oMissing, oMissing,
                oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
wb.SaveAs(svfileName, XlFileFormat.xlExcel8, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
app.Quit();
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12159513/969613).

Comment: That throws an exception: `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` COMEXception was unhandled. is it working at your end?

Comment: I think the xlExcel8 is creating the problem.

Comment: I just took the time to test the code above, it's working perfectly on my computer.

Comment: for some reason xlExcel8 isn't working for me. I am using exact code and it throws COM Exception. BTW i've added Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel v 12.0.0.0 (2007) will it make any difference ?

Comment: How about xlWorkbookNormal ? It worked perfectly and i guess it will even preserve Excel 2003 + features.

Comment: It may well do, I am using Office 2013 currently, and have tested this with 2010 in the past but not 2007, if so my mistake!

Comment: If you got Exception when using the code given above, check your Excel file if it has Macro code inside. Make sure the Macro code compatible with prior version of Excel..

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following snippet from [here](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support/articles/convert-xls-xlsx-ods-csv-html-net):

```
// Create new XLSX file.
var xlsxFile = new ExcelFile();

// Load data from XLSX file.
xlsxFile.LoadXlsx(fileName + ".xls", XlsxOptions.PreserveMakeCopy);

// Save XLSX file to XLS file.
xlsxFile.SaveXls(fileName + ".xls");
```

It uses [this component](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview).

Comment: That will add dependency in my application. o.O

Answer (score 0):

I think this has the answer you're looking for:

[What is the correct `XlFileFormat` enumeration for Excel 97-2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159513/what-is-the-correct-xlfileformat-enumeration-for-excel-97-2003)

You're using file format `xlOpenXMLTemplate`.  Try using `xlExcel8` instead? That should be the file format for 97-2003 Workbooks.

Comment: It threw an com exception. Could you create a console and check again?

Comment: I'm not in a position to do that unfortunately. I notice @JMK says this is working. I am certain that the fileformat you were previously, `xlOpenXMLTemplate` is incorrect. The `SaveAs` method should use the correct file format enumeration for an Excel 97-2003 Workbook (.xls), which should be xlExcel8.